# How do i shift a specific row in Dataframe using pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
Here is my data frame :
columns: 
        
        Index(['PID', 'ST_NUM', 'ST_NAME', 'OWN_OCCUPIED', 'NUM_BEDROOMS', 'NUM_BATH',
               'SQ_FT'],
              dtype='object')
        
data:
        array([[100001000.0, 104.0, 'PUTNAM', 'Y', 3.0, '1', 1000.0],
               [nan, 100001000.0, 104.0, 'PUTNAM', 'Y', 3.0, 3.0]], dtype=object)
```

here I need to shift the second row to left by 1 position

Comment: This may also be caused by importing the file in a wrong way. If that is the case I would rather look at importing at in the correct way instead of trying to fix it by shifting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to shift in pandas, you use `shift` method

```py
df.iloc[1].shift(-1)
```

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2], "B":[np.nan, 6]})
df.iloc[1].shift(-1)
```

results:

```
A    6.0
B    NaN
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

The argument in shift method: -1 for one position to the left, x for x positions to the right

You need to somehow filter the row of course. Here I just used the index (1) but you filter it in your favorite way